# How to send a json object that holds a file in it to Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I'm working on this simple Form application using Nodejs as my Server side. I'm able to receive the JSON object data sent by the Ajax call to Node. But my issue is that when I add a new property to my JSON object that will allow me to upload a file (data location:  `$('input[type=file]')[0].files`) the server doesn't get it and it throws me an error.

So how can I attach a new property that holds a file value to my json object so my server can receive it? or do I need to change my Ajax call differently?

Here's my code:

**script.js**

```
$("form").submit( function() {
hideError();
submit = submitAnswers();
if(submit == true){
  var jsonData = createJson();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/form',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsonData,
    // enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    // //contentType: 'application/json',
    error: function(err){
      console.log(err);
      showError(err.responseText);
    }
  });
}
});

function createJson(){
var answers = $("form[name = quizForm] input[type=radio]:checked")
var results = {
  authority:     answers[0].value == 'a',
  sharing:       answers[1].value == 'a',
  accuracy:      answers[2].value == 'a',
  quality:       answers[3].value == 'a',
  complete:      answers[4].value == 'a',
  format:        answers[5].value == 'a',
  type:          answers[6].value == 'a',
  ownership:     answers[7].value == 'a'
  datalocation:  $('input[type=file]')[0].files
}
return results;
}
```

**Server Code**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.sendfile('./public/html/form.html');
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

/*This verifies that json data was sent to Server after being executed by the Ajax call*/
console.log('Request received: ');
console.log(req.body) // this line helps you inspect the request so you can see whether the data is in the url (GET) or the req body (POST)
console.log('\nRequest recieved: \nmethod: ' + req.method + '\nurl: ' + req.url) // this line logs just the method and url

res.end('callback(\'{\"msg\": \"OK\"}\')');
```

Comment: use a FileReader to get the contents or use FormData instead of JSON

Comment: Well JSON type cannot contain file. You should post a multi-part kind of request.